# Determine the covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$ corresponding to subgroup of $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$ generated by cubes of all elements.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

This is exercise 1.3.13 in page 80 from Allen Hatcher's book [*Algebraic topology*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

> Determine the covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$ corresponding to subgroup of $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$ generated by cubes of all elements.

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for?  Do you have reason to believe there's a particularly simple description?

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be the subgroup of $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)$ generated by cubes.  First, note that $G$ is a characteristic subgroup, and in particular a normal subgroup.  The quotient $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)/G$ is thus the Burnside group $B(2,3)$: the group with two generators modulo the relations that the cube of every element is $1$.  Thus the covering space associated to $G$ can be identified with the Cayley graph of $B(2,3)$ with respect to its two canonical generators.

To be more explicit about the group $B(2,3)$, according to [this source](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Burnside_group), $B(2,3)$ has $27$ elements and is isomorphic to the group of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & y \\ 0 & 1 & z \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for $x,y,z\in\mathbb{F}_3$.  I would assume the two generators can be taken to be $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, but I have not checked the details.